# Will this loop run infinitely?

Tags: c

I am sitting in a class and I am told by a very experienced teacher that the following code will terminate when the `STACK memory` gets completely filled by the program. Now I am not able to understand why? Below Is the source code :-

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
char i;
for (i = 120; i < 130; i++)
    printf("\n%d", i);

return 0;
}
```

Now, the reason I feel that this loop will not terminate is because once the program runs, the variable is declared in one memory location which is not changing till the life of the program and we are only changing the value of the already declared variable. So, I wanted to ask the answer to this question. Also, if you think the teacher is right, please explain as well :)

Also, I tried running the program for a long time but the memory consumption did not increase by even a bit :|

Comment: You are cheating your teacher right now :)

Comment: Yes, because you're using `char`, when `i` reaches 127 the result of `i++` in next loop will be -128 and so on, So the loops goes forever.

Comment: @haccks - I don't think cheating but the problem with me is that I generally don't believe teachers until and unless I see that the code works in front of my eyes. :| (Which has proved beneficial in times uncountable :P)

Comment: The only way to fill the stack up with that program is if the stack is in the terminal emulation program from which you run the code. (Or if the program's own stack is far smaller than virtually any real program would use, even as long ago as 20 or 30 years.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The actions of the program depend on how your implementation defines `char`: [it may be a signed or an unsigned type](http://web.archive.org/web/20050207010641/http://dev.unicals.com/papers/c99-draft.html#6.2.5).

If it is unsigned, it outputs 10 numbers and terminates.

If it is signed, it will wrap at 127 and the next value is -128 - in most implementations. But according to the standard, it is undefined behaviour.

I don't see why it should eat up the complete stack - there is no recursion and no additional memory allocation, so that

> told by a very experienced teacher that the following code will terminate when the `STACK memory` gets completely filled by the program

means "never" - because it just doesn't fill up the stack. It cannot have been such an experienced programmer/teacher – or the OP is not an experienced listener and has misunderstood something the teacher has told him.

Comment: 10 numbers? `i` has been declared as `char` wont that change the fact

Comment: Consider what happens if char is an 8 bit signed type, as may well be the case

Comment: This is an infinite loop! I tested. o__O

Comment: @haccks Depending on how the implementation defines `char`. It is free to have it signed or unsigned.

Comment: @glglgl; You are right. I just tested it with `unsigned`.+1 for mentioning it.

Comment: @haccks I believe overflow of signed types is undefined behaviour by the letter of the standard (although wrapping is common).

Comment: @NigelHarper You are right. I always considered it as at least implementation-defined :-O But it is indeed UB.

Comment: @glglgl, I wouldn't draw a conclusion on the teacher, perhaps the OP was just not such an "experienced listener".

Comment: @NigelHarper; Yes. It is (I forgot about that). :)

Comment: @ glgl- The teacher and according to the environment, the variable was declared as signed. 
@JensGustedt - Umm, I don't think so that happened because I discussed this personally also after the class and don't worry I don't think that any teacher is just bad or so, a teacher is a teacher :)

Answer (score 3):

the reason is simple as well as tricky :)

`i` is not an **int**, but a **char**.
This means that its range goes from -128 to +127.

While the loop increses the index, it will overflow at +128, so that the value in memory will be -127 again. This means that `i` is again smaller than 130! The loop continues on and on...

Now continue cheating :P

Comment: `i is not an int, but a char. This means that its range goes from -128 to +127.`: No. No guarantee that `char` is either signed or `unsigned` unless specified. See the [glglgl's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21182902/2455888).

Comment: This is right, but I haven't seen very often that char is by default unsigned. In addition, I wanted to help the understanding, why it's probably an infinite loop

Comment: Apart from what @haccks said, note that overflow on signed types invokes undefined behavior. Only unsigned overflow is guaranteed to wrap around. While this answer is correct for most of the practical real world uses, it is technically poor and lacks important details.

Comment: I'm not going to add these details since her/his teachers intention was to raise awareness of overflows.

Comment: @MyPasswordIsLasercats - Not cheating, the teacher asked the question to give output of the program and I said that infinite loop, then he told what I have told above. But yea +1 that his intention was to raise awareness about the overflows ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it will lead to infinite loop since `i` has been declared as `char` which ranges from **-128 to +127** so it never reached 130

the time `i` reaches **127** it comes back to **-128** and never reaches **130**

http://ideone.com/iVLoHe

Answer (score 0):

char is 1byte long -2^8 to 2^8-1 (-128 to 127) if you try to add 1 to 127 it will be -128 an overflow occurs. 
printing the variable you will see the same .

change the declartion from 
         char i  to int i

it never fills the stack as you are not declaring new variables or calling functions to fill the stack. so it's an infinite loop only